# AJAX Call to MVC Action Method fails

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC Application with an Angular front end. I have an AJAX call that automatically pulls data from a Connected Service via an Action Method in the Home Controller on page load.

I am debugging an Error that is getting throw by the AJAX `get` method and can't figure out what's wrong.

Here are the pieces

The Action Method:

```
public JsonResult DataRefresh()
{
    string data = ServiceCache.NewDataCheck(DataConfig.currentUser.UserName);

    return Json(data);
}
```

I set a [break-point to confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hfCA.png) that `data` holds the appropriately formatted Json string

Here is the AJAX Call + the Angular controller that contains it:

```
// Stores the serialized contents of the view model
app.controller("processModel", function ($scope) {
    $scope.sortType = 'SchedWk';
    $scope.sortReverse = false;

    $scope.GetData = function() {
        LoadData();
    };

    function LoadData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'Home/DataRefresh',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              $scope.data = data;
            }, 
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert("The jqXHR object:  " + a + " Error Type:  " + b + " Error Description:  " + c);
            }
        });

        return false;
    };  

});
```

I successfully call this method on page load which hits the above Action Method, but I get the following Error:

[image]

This is my first project that uses AJAX so I have almost no idea how to decipher this error message. I read through the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and there isn't any additional information as to what those specific error message values could indicate.

The most useful info I can intuit is that it's not a Parse Error so the format the returned JSON string is likely correct.

UPDATE:

I added `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` to the return in the JsonResult Action Method and that stopped the error from getting thrown, however I still don't have any data. I think it may be a problem with trying to access Angular $scope directly within an AJAX function.

Comment: check your devtools->network tab and see the response body of the ajax call

Comment: `console.log(a,b,c)` will give you a better debugging experience than `alert()`.

Comment: @Shyju I can't seem to find this tab under Tools in Visual Studio 2017. Is it an extension that I need to install?

Comment: @user3776749 devtools are a part of the browser generally you can press F12 to reach them.